# want to make multiple flags in script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, flags

I want to make a multiple flags for my script. And didn't work like what I want it.

```
    #!/bin/bash

function wherecpy
{
    echo "Plaes write where the files are located: "
    read placefile
    cd $placefile
}

function funcpy
{
    wherecpy
    echo ""
    echo "Please choose the following:"
    echo ""
    echo "1. Interactive copy, answer yes or no (y/n) before doing the copy"
    echo "2. Make backups of existing destination files"
    echo "3. Preserve file attributes"
    echo "4. Do a recursively copy"
    echo "5. Back to main menu"
    echo ""
        echo -n "Enter Your Selection: "
        read selection
        echo ""
    case $selection in
        1) a="-i" ;;
        2) b="--backup" ;;
        3) c="--preserve=all" ;;
        4) d="-r" ;;
        0) return 0 ;;
    esac
    echo "Type the name of the file you wish to copy/backup: "
    read file
    echo "Type the name of the destination file/directory: "
    read dest
    cp $a $b $c $d "$file" "$dest"
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "Success"
    else
    echo "failed."
    fi

}
```

I want it to work like that :

> Please type in the source file(s) to copy:
>   File1 file2 file3
>   Please type in the destination:
>     dir1
>   Copy successful.
>   Press any key to return to main menu.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What about the script isn't doing what you want exactly?

Comment: What I want to do is I want to select more than one option at a time. For example I want that I can copy and backup a file at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getopts` :

There are many [online resources](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) you can take reference from